# Django Login page looping

Tags: python, html, django

I created a user base with login and registration page, and everything worked fine, i was able to click on the logout button and it would log me out to the login page, but now it stopped, and I cant seem to even access The login page as I get the following error in CMD:

```
[04/Aug/2021 17:21:22] "GET /Logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[04/Aug/2021 17:21:22] "GET /Login/?next=/Logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[04/Aug/2021 17:21:22] "GET /Login/?next=/Login/%3Fnext%3D/Logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[04/Aug/2021 17:21:22] "GET /Login/?next=/Login/%3Fnext%3D/Login/%253Fnext%253D/Logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[04/Aug/2021 17:21:22] "GET /Login/?next=/Login/%3Fnext%3D/Login/%253Fnext%253D/Login/%25253Fnext%25253D/Logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[04/Aug/2021 17:21:22] "GET /Login/?next=/Login/%3Fnext%3D/Login/%253Fnext%253D/Login/%25253Fnext%25253D/Login/%2525253Fnext%2525253D/Logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[04/Aug/2021 17:21:22] "GET /Login/?next=/Login/%3Fnext%3D/Login/%253Fnext%253D/Login/%25253Fnext%25253D/Login/%2525253Fnext%2525253D/Login/%252525253Fnext%252525253D/Logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[04/Aug/2021 17:21:22] "GET /Login/?next=/Login/%3Fnext%3D/Login/%253Fnext%253D/Login/%25253Fnext%25253D/Login/%2525253Fnext%2525253D/Login/%252525253Fnext%252525253D/Login/%25252525253Fnext%25252525253D/Logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

What I understood is that it redirects you to your login page, which isn't public. Which then redirects you again back to the login page, so on and so on.

But I cant understand what is wrong with my code.

VIEWS:

```
@login_required(login_url='Login')
def Auditor(request):
    model = datas.objects.filter(qs_login=request.user)

    form = auditForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = auditForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # <-- Add this to get the updated data instance

    context = {'items': model, 'form': form}
    return render(request, "main/auditform.html", context)

@login_required(login_url='Login')
def auditFormPage(request, pk):
    model = datas.objects.filter(qs_login=request.user)
    form = auditForm()
    try:
        data = datas.objects.get(Task_ID=pk)

        form = auditForm(instance=data)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = auditForm(request.POST, instance=data)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()  # <-- Add this to get the updated data instance
          
    except datas.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    context = {
        "items": model,
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "main/auditform.html", context)


def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('Auditor')
    else:

        form = createUserForm()

        if request.method == "POST":
            form = createUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, 'Account Successfully Created for: ' + user)
                return redirect('Login')

        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'main/register.html', context)


def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('Auditor')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('Auditor')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Username or Password is incorrect.')

        context = {}

        return render(request, 'main/login.html', context)


def logoutPage(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('Login')
```

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Auditor, name='Auditor'),
    path('<str:pk>/', views.auditFormPage, name='AuditForm'),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name='Register'),
    path('Login/', views.loginPage, name='Login'),
    path('Logout/', views.logoutPage, name='Logout'),
    

]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if user is not None:
  login(request, user)
  return redirect('Login')
```

Here you are redirecting the user to the login page again when the user is logged in. Try to redirect it to somewhere else, like the homepage.

Comment: SMART! i didnt notice that, but I did that and I still get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

In your logon view logic you keep redirect the user to the login page.

```
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('Login')
```

You should redirect to the requested page or set login redirect url in your settings.
Try to something like

```
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('auditor')
```

Comment: SMART! i didnt notice that, but I did that and I still get the same error...

Comment: Get rid of the if  statement at beginning since your are now redirecting to another page once the user is authenticated. And check return indentation of the login page

Comment: I tried removing if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('Auditor')  even removing the redirect when the user is not none... I dont know what to do! it was working perfectly before.

Comment: Please check the indentation of the last return It seems like you are constently calling the login page and clean your browser caches or do ctrl shift r

Comment: So i updated the main question VIEWS. As i dont get that loop anymore BUT When i click on logout it keeps me in the same Auditor page! Would have any idea? like if i go to /Logout /Login it just retakes me back to the Auditor page(Home Page)